# Deserialize enum ignoring case in Spring Boot controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I have Spring Boot endpoint which has enum as query param:

```
@GetMapping("/example")
public List<Example> getByEnum(@RequestParam(name = "exampleEnum", required = false) ExampleEnum exampleEnum) {
    // code
}
```

And enum class:

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
}
```

If I pass uppercase enum value to the endpoit, it deserializes well but it throws error for lowercase:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
```

How to deserialize enum ignoring case in Spring Boot Rest endpoint?

This question is not duplicate because it's related to query param deserialization.

Comment: Not a duplicate as the question refers specifically to query string parameters which are handled differently to attributes of a post body.

Comment: SIGH - both answers are wrong and I am not able to provide a correct answer as the question has been closed as a duplicate by people who don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: @Dave I have modified question. Could you press reopen below the question?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**EDIT:** The answer below is incorrect. You have to define a custom `PropertyEditor` and register it with Spring `@InitBinder` which I explained [in this post](https://kdowbecki.github.io/Case-insentivie-enum-mapping-with-RequestParam/). Thanks to @Dave for pointing this out in the comments.

---

Spring Boot 2.0 is using Jackson 2.9 which has [ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/pull/1520) feature. You should be able to enable it by setting

```
spring.jackson.mapper.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS = true
```

property as per [docs, Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: Added property and objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS); but still get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant

Comment: Most likely the `objectMapper` you are configuring is not the one used by web layer. Use the Spring Boot properties as in my example and then check. See `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` class.

Comment: I have used both: spring boot property and enabled on custom object mapper. Custom ObjectMapper config is marked as \@Bean \@Primary so it should work for all layers.

Comment: Jackson doesn't even get a look-in here because we are not deserializing a message body - Spring MVC is instead _converting_ a request param. For this purpose Spring uses the DataBinder's registered PropertyEditors or, failing that, a matching TypeConverter from the web ConversionService. To resolve this issue you should extend PropertyEditorSupport and add an @InitBinder annotated method which registers it to your controller.

Comment: using `jackson.mapper.accept-case-insensitive-enums: true` seems to be working fine in spring boot 3.x

Answer (score 6):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public enum ExampleEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND;

    @JsonCreator
    public static ExampleEnum setValue(String key) {
        return Arrays.stream(ExampleEnum.values())
            .filter(exampleEnum -> exampleEnum.toString().equals(key.toUpperCase()))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Still using Optionals like this, huh? should have been optional.orElse(null). See Stuart Mark's talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14

Comment: then use orElse(null) instead of the if else

Answer (score 2):

You can make generic converter for all enums

```
package ru.grancall.kb.logging.service.dto.converter;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

@AllArgsConstructor
public class EnumConverter extends PropertyEditorSupport {
    private Class type;

    public void setAsText(String text) {
        setValue(EnumUtils.getEnum(type, text.toUpperCase()));
    }
}
```

And then in any of your Controllers use it:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(YourEnum.class, new EnumConverter(YourEnum.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get ALL your enums handled case-insensitively you can use Spring's [ApplicationConversionService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/convert/ApplicationConversionService.html).

You only have to register it with the following little Configuration (see [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-enum-mapping#1-using-applicationconversionservice)):

```
@Configuration
public class EnumMappingConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        ApplicationConversionService.configure(registry);
    }
}
```